# Getting list of visible, named windows in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, win32gui

I am trying to get a list of open windows. I am stuck at this point. I have commented everything that does not work so far.

```
import win32gui

def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):

    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) != "":
            wnd_name = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
            print(f'Type: {type(wnd_name)} Name: {wnd_name}')

            # return wnd_name
        # return wnd_name
    # return wnd_name

win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
```

This is an example of the output.

```
Type: <class 'str'> Name: vksts
Type: <class 'str'> Name: *new 10 - Notepad++
Type: <class 'str'> Name: _Chrome Downloads
Type: <class 'str'> Name: Microsoft Text Input Application
Type: <class 'str'> Name: Settings
Type: <class 'str'> Name: Program Manager
```

Although `wnd_name` is a string and I can print it, I can't figure out how to get its value to the main part of the script.

When I uncomment the 1st `return wnd_name`, I get the error message `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)` for the line `win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)`.

When I uncomment the 2nd or 3rd `return wnd_name`, I get the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'wnd_name' referenced before assignment` for the line `return wnd_name`.

While `win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)` is looping through the windows, how do I capture each window title and feed it to a list so that I end up with something like `['vksts','*new 10 - Notepad++','_Chrome Downloads',...]`?

Comment: did you google it? first hit:   [https://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/win32-python-getting-all-window-titles/](https://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/win32-python-getting-all-window-titles/) seems to work

Comment: While I am trying to teach myself "how" to do things, I also want to know "why" things do or do not work. That's why I wanted to know why the "return" statement didn't return like I thought it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handler functions are something that are called by the code you provide it to.
You try to return a string from the handler function you provide.

You get an error of `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)` - that means that inside `win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)` the returnvalue of your function (a string) is used for something that needs an integer - most probably the windowid/hwndid.

The other errors are because you left the scope of the variable if no window title is given so the variable is never instantiated and can not be returned because it is not know...

> ```
> def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx): 
>     if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
>         if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) != "":
>             # you define the variable here
>             wnd_name = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
>             print(f'Type: {type(wnd_name)} Name: {wnd_name}') 
>             return wnd_name
>         # if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)  == "" the wnd_name is never
>         # created in the first place, so you get the UnboundLocalError 
>         return wnd_name
>     return wnd_name
> ```

You can try if

```
import win32gui

names = []

def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        n = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)  
        if n:
            names.append(n)
            print(n)

win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

print(names)
```

works for you.